# Is there a way to find all untranslated strings in React application automatically?

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, react-i18next

I'm working on internationalization via i18n in legacy project.

The problem is that some strings are translated and some not.

Is there a way to find all untranslated strings automatically, not manually? (Strings that not wrapped in `t(some text)`?

Comment: Which library are you using for the i18n stuff in your project?

Comment: we have react-i18next.